# Select objective and prevent them from repeating

Tags: c

I need to generate the next shot with the `t_disparos` matrix.  How can I generate a random coordinate between `0` and `dim`, and prevent the random numbers repeating?

```
void pSeleccionarObjetivoAuto(int *f, int *c, char t_disparos[][T_DIM_MAX],
                              unsigned int dim, bool hundido)
{

}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking, to be able to present any kind of solution.

Comment: You can't stop the random numbers repeating; you can simply detect that they are a repeat and ignore them, requesting more random numbers until things don't repeat.  Just make sure there is a possible solution.

Comment: I've attempted to translate your question — I hope I didn't distort anything.  It still isn't clear.  You've not explained what `f`, `c` or `hundido` do, nor explained how many random coordinates you need.  Is T_DIM_MAX the value 2, 3, or something bigger?  Are the `char` values in `t_diparos` characters or small integers — and if integers, do you expect them to be signed or unsigned (since the standard says plain `char` may be either).